# how to stop looping json if data found

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to search if data exist on my object and this code work as I expected,but I have problem when showing result. It show all index I have on my object.

How I stop looping if result was found in my object

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var myData = {
  "animals":[{
   "name":"cat"
  },
  {
   "name":"dog"
  },
  {
   "name":"horse"
  },
  {
   "name":"bear"
  }
  ]};

 $('#send').click(function(){
  var res = $('#animal').val();
  
  $.each(myData.animals, function(i,j){
   if(j.name == res){
    console.log('found');
   }
   else{
    console.log('not found');
   }
  });

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myData">
 <input type="text" id='animal'>
 <button id='send'>find</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of trying to stop a loop, use a method more fit to the task such as filter.  http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-elements

Comment: To break each use `return false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myData = {
    "animals": [
      {
        "name": "cat"
      },
      {
        "name": "dog"
      },
      {
        "name": "horse"
      },
      {
        "name": "bear"
      }
    ]
  };

  $('#send').on('click', function() {
    var res = $('#animal').val();
    
    var foundAnimal = myData.animals.find(function(animal){
      return animal.name === res;
    });
    
    console.log('Animal Found: '+ !!foundAnimal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myData">
 <input type="text" id='animal'>
 <button id='send'>find</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than using jQuery, you can also use [`array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function

```js
const myData = {"animals":[{"name":"cat"},{"name":"dog"},{"name":"horse"},{"name":"bear"}]};

const res = "horse";

var result = myData['animals'].find((animal) => {
    return animal['name'] === res;
});

console.log(result);
```